# weird inaccuracy in line rotation - c++

Tags: c++

I have programmed a simple [dragon curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_curve) fractal. It seems to work for the most part, but there is an odd logical error that shifts the rotation of certain lines by one pixel. This wouldn't normally be an issue, but after a few generations, at the right size, the fractal begins to look wonky.

[image: close up of the fractal]
[image: after a few generations]

I am using open cv in c++ to generate it, but I'm pretty sure it's a logical error rather than a display error. I have printed the values to the console multiple times and seen for myself that there is a one-digit difference between values that are intended to be the exact same - meaning a line may have a y of 200 at one end and 201 at another.

Here is the full code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
const int width=500;
const int height=500;
const double PI=std::atan(1)*4.0;
struct point{
  double x;
  double y;
  point(double x_,double y_){
    x=x_;
    y=y_;
  }};

cv::Mat img(width,height,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255,255,255));

double deg_to_rad(double degrees){return degrees*PI/180;}

point rotate(int degree, int centx, int centy, int ll) {
  double radians = deg_to_rad(degree);

  return point(centx + (ll * std::cos(radians)), centy + (ll * std::sin(radians)));
}
void generate(point & r, std::vector < point > & verticies, int rotation = 90) {
  int curRotation = 90;
  bool start = true;
  point center = r;
  point rot(0, 0);
  std::vector<point> verticiesc(verticies);

  for (point i: verticiesc) {
    double dx = center.x - i.x;
    double dy = center.y - i.y;
    //distance from centre
    int ll = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
   //angle from centre
    curRotation = std::atan2(dy, dx) * 180 / PI;
    //add 90 degrees of rotation
    rot = rotate(curRotation + rotation, center.x, center.y, ll);
    verticies.push_back(rot);
   //endpoint, where the next centre will be 
    if (start) {

      r = rot;
      start = false;
    }
  }
}
void gen(int gens, int bwidth = 1) {
  int ll = 7;
  std::vector < point > verticies = {
    point(width / 2, height / 2 - ll),
    point(width / 2, height / 2)
  };
  point rot(width / 2, height / 2);
  for (int i = 0; i < gens; i++) {
    generate(rot, verticies);
  }
//draw lines
  for (int i = 0; i < verticies.size(); i += 2) {
    cv::line(img, cv::Point(verticies[i].x, verticies[i].y), cv::Point(verticies[i + 1].x, verticies[i + 1].y), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8);
  }
}
int main() {
  gen(10);
  cv::imshow("", img);
  cv::waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered IEEE-754 rounding errors and using Ceiling/Floor/Round to workaround the issue?

Comment: In the "distance from centre" calculation, what is `ll` supposed to be?  A truncated square root, a rounded value, or the actual (double) square root?  Assigning a double to an int will truncate, and lose the fraction.

Comment: @Dai thank you! It worked! - I rounded the values, and you were right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was to do with floating-point precision. I changed

```
x=x_;
y=y_;
```

to

```
x=std::round(x_);
y=std::round(y_);
```

and it works.

Answer (score 1):

First, you use `int` to store point coordinates - that's a bad idea - you lose all accuracy of point position. Use `double` or `float`.

Second, your method for drawing fractals is not too stable numericly. You'd better store original shape and all rotation/translation/scale that indicate where and how to draw scaled copies of the original shape.

Also, I believe this is a bug:

```
for(point i: verices)
{
    ...
    vertices.push_back(rot);
    ...
}
```

Changing size of vertices while inside such a for-loop might cause a crash or UB.

Comment: Nice catch. One should always read the documentation (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) before using a container for which he does not know invalidation rules.

Comment: You are right on all of your points, I have changed the iterated vector to a copy of ```verticies ``` and changed the x and y of ```point``` to doubles. But alas, it is still wonky.

Comment: `int` is just fine for coordinates and maintains precision far better than floating point types. The real issue here is compounded precision errors.